# Is there a search option for images?

Tags: support, search, images

Is there a search option that selects the posts that contains an attached image? Something as the option  for the search of a code?

Comment: See also this feature request on meta.SE: [Add “hasImage:1” or “img:1” advanced search operators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156639). Some other related posts might also contain useful information and various workarouns. For example, [Can I search for questions with images?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266138) and  [Search all of my past questions that had images or screenshots in them?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257901)

Comment: And there is also a related older post on this meta: [What is the efficient way to search post with pictures/images?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9402)